# Was Jesus really born in a manger?

Tags: jesus, luke

While reading about [protoevangelium](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/7127/42957) noticed the following description of Jesus

> Jesus was Eve's offspring, naturally. He was born to a virgin, was the
> son of a carpenter, born in lowly Bethlehem, **in a manger**, and raised
> in despicable Nazareth. He was born in a state of humility.

and realized that's not the only person I've stumbled accross that thinks Jesus was born in a manger (some sort of keeping place for animals). If you read the book fro Timothy Keller God's Wisdom for Navigating Live, in the devotional for 26th of December,

> ... who was born in a manger for you ...

And these are not the only locations where such statement (Jesus is born in a manger) can be found

- https://www.gotquestions.org/Jesus-manger.html
- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/why-jesus-born-manger-s-r-morris/
- https://www.quora.com/Why-was-Jesus-born-in-a-manger

---

From what's written in Luke 2:7 [NASB]

> And she gave birth to her firstborn son; and she wrapped Him in
> cloths, and laid Him in a manger, because there was no room for them
> in the inn.

In portuguese BPT that's even less evident (which could explain the confusion)

> Nasceu-lhe então o menino, que era o seu primeiro filho. Envolveu-o em
> panos e deitou-o numa manjedoura, por não conseguirem arranjar lugar
> na casa.

It states something within the lines

> The boy was born to her, who was her first child. She wrapped him in
> cloths and laid him in a manger, as they could not find a place in the
> house.

Comment: _What we know is that the child was not born in the inn (there was no room). And what we know is that he was laid in a manger (where animals feed)._ These are the facts.

Comment: Right @NigelJ, I didn't question any of these. Yet I don't think we can know for certain if he was born in the manger or not. I'll read in the original language to see if it's clearer there...

Comment: Sir, did it never occur to you that the scripture is _deliberately being sensitive_ to the woman and to the intimacy of her bringing forth the child. Due to the distressing circumstances, a veil is being drawn over the actual details.

Comment: @NigelJ that would be one way to see it too which makes more sense in the light of someone knowing for sure that Jesus was born in a manger and unless you read it elsewhere this would be the passage dealing with it.

Comment: Is this whole question about one person's 8-year-old summary on the Christianity Q&A that (somewhat) sloppily conflates the moment of Jesus's birth and his subsequent being placed in a manger? What's the point of the question? Yes, as you see, the text just says he was placed in it, not that Mary's labour took place in one.

Comment: @curiousdannii so we cannot affirm without any doubt that he was born in a manger like commonly read and hence the necessity for this question. And please if you can refrain from being rude or does that make you feel better?

Comment: Is it really commonly said that Jesus was born in a manger? I think it's much more commonly said that he was born in a stable *and then placed in a manger*. One person does not mean it's common. If you have an issue with their post, you should write a comment on it. To justify a question here you should show that it really is common. BTW, I edited that post to add "placed". I don't think there's any reason to think the author really thought Jesus was born in a manger.

Comment: @curiousdannii I can't prove you why I say it's common due to being verbal contacts and so changed the wording. If you still will some places where that same question was asked (pointing to more people with the same misconception), [1](https://www.gotquestions.org/Jesus-manger.html), [2](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/why-jesus-born-manger-s-r-morris/), [3](https://www.quora.com/Why-was-Jesus-born-in-a-manger), ...

Comment: @curiousdannii I gave another reference to address «One person does not mean it's common».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word φάτνη (phatné) occurs just four times in the NT - all in the Gospel of Luke, namely, Luke 2:7, 12, 16, 13:15.

Thayer gives the following meaning:

> φάτνη, φάτνης, ἡ ((πατέομαι to eat; Vanicek, p. 445)), a crib, manger:
> Luke 2:7, 12, 16; Luke 13:15. (From Homer down; the Sept. for אֵבוּס,
> Job 39:9; Proverbs 14:4; Isaiah 1:3; plural for רְפָתִים, Habakkuk
> 3:17.)

BDAG suggests: "***manger, crib***".

The Cambridge commentary observes:

> in a manger; If the Received Text were correct it would be ‘in the
> manger,’ but the article is omitted by A, B, D, L. Phatnç is sometimes
> rendered ‘stall’ (as in Luke 13:15; 2 Chronicles 32:28, LXX.); but
> ‘manger’ is probably right here. It is derived from pateomai, ‘I eat’
> (Curtius, Griech. Et. ii. 84), and is used by the LXX. for the Hebrew.
> אֵבוּם ‘crib,’ in Proverbs 14:4. Mangers are very ancient, and are to
> this day sometimes used as cradles in the East (Thomson, Land and
> Book, ii. 533). The ox and the ass which are traditionally represented
> in pictures are only mentioned in the apocryphal Gospel of Matthew ,
> 14, and were suggested by Isaiah 1:3, and Habakkuk 3:2, which in the
> LXX. and the ancient Latin Version (Vetus Itala) was mistranslated
> “Between two animals thou shalt be made known.”

Barnes has some helpful comments:

> Laid him in a manger - The word rendered "inn" in this verse means
> simply a place of halting, a lodging-place; in modern terms, a khan or
> caravanserai (Robinson's "Biblical Research in Palestine," iii. 431).
> The word rendered "manger" means simply a crib or place where cattle
> were fed. "Inns," in our sense of the term, were anciently unknown in
> the East, and now they are not common. Hospitality was generally
> practiced, so that a traveler had little difficulty in obtaining
> shelter and food when necessary. As traveling became more frequent,
> however, khans or caravanserais were erected for public use - large
> structures where the traveler might freely repair and find lodging for
> himself and his beast, he himself providing food and forage. Many such
> khans were placed at regular intervals in Persia. To such a place it
> was, though already crowded, that Joseph and Mary resorted at
> Bethlehem. Instead of finding a place in the "inn," or the part of the
> caravanserai where the travelers themselves found a place of repose,
> they were obliged to be contented in one of the stalls or recesses
> appropriated to the beasts on which they rode.

There is much more in Barnes - too much to reproduce here.  However, that Jesus was laid in an animal feed trough or manger is beyond doubt; however, just what arrangement of stable vs sleeping quarters is unknown.  It is possible, for example, that Joseph and his small family were allowed to stay in the animal keepers quarters and the parents found the manger convenient.

*Edit to further clarify*: Neither the Bible nor any other source says that Jesus was literally born in a manger; one assumes Jesus was born while Mary gave birth on some make-shift bed in the stable or whatever it was where they were staying.  It was following that birth that Jesus was wrapped in strips of cloth (scrap of some kind) and then laid in a manger.

Comment: Yes I'm not questioning the fact that he was laid in a manger. Rather, the bible references that after he was born he was laid there but doesn't specify he was born there too

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 -  I am not sure that is the intention of "born in a manger".  It is presumably idiom for that is where is was first placed to "laid" to sleep.

Comment: can you make the answer to the question more explicit? So that I can accept it.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 - I have tried to make the answer as explicit within the limits of what has been revealed.